# Android eclipse random string array for setText?

Tags: android, arrays, button, random, settext

If I understand correctly

```
    Random ran = new Random();
    String[] ButtonText = null;
    Resources res = getResources();
    ButtonText = res.getStringArray(R.array.ButtonText_array);
    String strRandom = ButtonText[ran.nextInt(ButtonText.length)];
    System.out.println("Random string is : "+strRandom);
```

Is a way to take my string-array items and put them in random order and now I'm wanting to setText of several buttons with individual items from the strRandom. The following is for the setText of a button

```
    Button gm1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gm1);
    gm1.setText();
```

But I dont know how to put in the strRandom items into the setText part and since I dont need it displaying what do I need to alter here.

`System.out.println("Random string is : "+strRandom);`

Answer (score 2):

I really am not understanding the question...

If you're just asking how to set the text to a random string, do it just as you did with the `println()` statement,

```
gm1.setText(strRandom);
```

or

```
gm1.setText(ButtonText[ran.nextInt(ButtonText.length)]);
```

Just a side note: by convention, variables are done in camelCase, reserve AllCaps for class names. (e.g. ButtonText should be buttonText). You'll notice the SO formatter formats ButtonText as if it were a class, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
gm1.setText((CharSequence)("Random string is : " + strRandom));
```

You need to cast from String to CharSequence

Comment: It's not necessary to cast to CharSequence from a String.